# Como fazer um footer em slider rodando os parceiros do site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom, já vi isso em alguns sites até procurei na internet algum exemplo mas não achei então vou pedir ajuda aqui.

Já vi isso em alguns sites e agora estou precisando implementar um *footer* em *slider* rodando os parceiros do site, se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato.

Segue o exemplo que eu vi: [Link do site](http://brouaventuras.com.br/).

Antes do *footer* do site tem a div parceiros gostaria de uma igual se alguém puder me ajudar ai.

Minha galeria que eu quero que faça isso:

```css
.mt {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

/* CLIENTS */

.clients img {
    max-width: 140px;
    max-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.clients .col-sm-2 {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt" >
            <div class="row clients centered" >
                <p class="mb "><b>Parceiros</b></p>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <img src="assets/img/client1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/client3.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/client2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/client4.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/client5.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/container-->
    </div>
    <!--/.G-->
```

Comment: O site que você postou utiliza o [owl.carousel.js](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html)

Answer (score 4):

Analisando o código fonte site que você postou, podemos ver que ele utiliza o [owl.carousel.js](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html), conforme o código abaixo:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://brouaventuras.com.br/wp-content/themes/consulting/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js?ver=3.4'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var owlRtl = false;
        if( $('body').hasClass('rtl') ) {
            owlRtl = true;
        }
        $("#owl-5a05a531b739d").owlCarousel({
            rtl: owlRtl,
                            autoplay: true,
                            dots: false,
                            loop: true,
                            autoplayTimeout: 1000,
            smartSpeed: 250,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 2                    },
                768: {
                    items: 4                    },
                980: {
                    items: 5                    },
                1199: {
                    items: 6                    }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo de como implementá-lo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 1000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    dots: true,
    items: 2,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3]
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item {
  margin: 3px;
}

#owl-demo .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page {
  display: inline-block;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #869791;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="owl-demo">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo de referência no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/)

Comment: Cara testei aqui mas não funcionou, editei meu post la da uma olhada

Comment: @TúlioGomes Veja as duas respostas, ambas possuem scripts das bibliotecas que utilizamos. O seu código não está referenciando as mesmas. Outro ponto é o javascript que colocamos, sem ele não irá funcionar.

Comment: Cara esse e meu código puro claro que quando eu fui colocar aqui eu fiz a chamada dos links e claro que eu adicionei o bloco de código em js e nenhum dos dois funcionou

Comment: @TúlioGomes Infelizmente não podemos ajudar sem ver o código real. Veja que nossos exemplos estão funcionando perfeitamente no site, então o erro está em algum lugar do seu código.

Comment: Voce teria skype para poder te mostrar meu codigo? @Randrade

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma biblioteca chamada [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) assim como a [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html) que você pode usar para fazer esse efeito de transição, e que é específica para isso. Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> para ter uma visualização de como funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.customer-logos').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 520,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
        }
    }]
});
});
```

```css
/* Slider */
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<div class="customer-logos">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>
</div>
```

Exemplo retirado [deste JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/huten0wq/).

Comment: Cara testei aqui mas não funcionou, editei meu post la da uma olhada